# Typescript Generic as Parameter

Tags: typescript, generics, reflection, prototypal-inheritance, type-safety

I have a class:

```
export class BaseClass<T> {
    constructor(data?: Partial<T>) {
        Object.assign(this, data);
    }
    name: string;
    id: number;
}
```

From this class, I extend the properties:

```
export class ExampleOne extends BaseClass<ExampleOne> {
    isReusable: boolean;
}

export class ExampleTwo extends BaseClass<ExampleTwo> {
    propOne: string;
    propTwo: boolean;

}
```

I've used a mapped type in BaseClass so that I could have "similar" syntax to that of C# to initialize an object as well as reuse the constructor in subsequent, classes that inherit BaseClass.

```
var x = new ExampleTwo({name: 'test', id: 1, propOne: 'test', propTwo: false});
```

This all seems to be working fine, but I would like to pass any one of these derived classes as a parameter to another function.

```
testFunction(data: BaseClass<T>) {
    //logic
}
```

I receive an error stating that the build `Cannot find name T`. I changed the signature to

```
testFunction(data: BaseClass<any>) {
    //logic
}
```

and that appeared to work, but I feel like there should be a better way to handle this.

What am I missing?

Comment: What is `testFunction()` a member of?

Comment: In my case, it would be a member of another class, not any of the inherited classes.

Comment: Try `testFunction<T>(data: BaseClass<T>)`

Comment: Ah, yes, that appears to work.

Comment: So, follow up question, it looks like "any" also worked in this case, and it restricted the types being passed in to only the inherited types. What is the better option?

Comment: They're equivalent in the code you've shared, but if you want to have access to type-safe reflection like `keyof T` for example, then you have to use the generic `T` instead of `any`.

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much. I'll accept your answer if you post one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution works, but only if you access `data` in your `// logic` as an *opaque* object. This means that you're only passing it around as a reference and your logic doesn't care what properties the object has other than what exists on the `BaseClass`.

In order for it to be accessible as a *transparent* object, which would allow type-safe reflection of the instance like `keyof`, etc., you should use the generic type parameter `T` like this:

```
testFunction<T>(data: BaseClass<T>) {
  // logic
}
```

The reason that your first attempt resulted in an error is because the class that `testFunction` is a member of, is evidently not a generic class like `class Foo<T> { ... }`, it's just `class Foo { ... }`.

If you have several functions in the class that need access to the type `T` then I recommend making it a generic class so you don't have to add the type parameter `<T>` to each individual member method.